# Changing App Title with Nav Drawer Menu Selection

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

So I am trying to create an app where when I click a menu item in the navigation drawer, it will change the application label name to the name of what was selected. I have searched for an answer but couldn't find anything. Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by application label name?

Comment: search for `setTitle` in Toolbar

Comment: Please add more information to your question, for example some code examples or sketches describing your UI.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach I added an answer that ended up solving my issue. Not sure how "correct" it is, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the title at the top ? If yes than you can do it by:

```
String currentActiviyName = "My Activity";

Toolbar activityToolbar = findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar_id);
setSupportActionBar(activityToolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar != null) {
   getSupportActionBar.setTitle(currentActiviyName);
}
```

This will be called in every activity that you want to specify a title at top.

**Tip :** If you're going to use it in so many activites you may want to create a BaseActivity, and add this as a method in there and then make your other activities extend it. Than by just calling the method you will be able to set the title you want.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

So I did the following and it seems to work. Obviously I put in the what I want each string to be in the string.xml file.

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment()).commit();
        setTitle(R.string.speed_graph);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment()).commit();
        setTitle(R.string.drive_player);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
        setTitle(R.string.google_maps);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in every Fragment,

```
@Override 

public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
}
```